# Looking for roof bike rack that fits a 2014 Specialized Demo 8

Tags: car-rack

Anyone at all know what roof bike racks, fit a 2014 Specialized demo 8

Comment: As far as MTB sizing goes, the bike is nothing special . Some racks won't support the 2.5" stock tires, but apart from that any rack will work.

Answer (score 1):

Any normal bike rack for cars should hold a bicycle like yours.

It's more for you to choose if you want a rear rack, or a roof rack, if you have a hitch or a towball, or if you want the rack to strap to the boot/trunk/hatch of the car.

Or you could just ride the bike and leave the car at home.